# How to make checkboxes work inside templates loop with DNN7 (Knockout)

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, knockout.js, dotnetnuke

I have this code running on DNN7.
To get checkboxes to work they have to be added a class "normalCheckbox". 
In the code below, the first checkbox outside det templates loop works fine, but the checkboxes in the accordion is not possible to click.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="onlychapter" data-bind="checked: myChkboxGlobal" class="filter-chkbox normalCheckBox"  /><label for="myChkboxGlobal" class="filter"  >Checkbox that works</label><br />
      <!-- -- ACCORDIAN  ACCORDIAN  ACCORDIAN  ACCORDIAN  ACCORDIAN  ACCORDIAN  ACCORDIAN  ACCORDIAN  ACCORDIAN  ACCORDIAN -- -->
            <div>    
                <h2 class="accordion ui-widget-header"> Project Assets</h2>
                <div id="accordion" data-bind="jqAccordion: { },template: { name: 'item-template', foreach: Items,  afterAdd: function(elem){$(elem).trigger('valueChanged');} }" ></div>                     
            </div>


<script type="text/html" id="item-template" >
    <div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'item' + itemId}, click: $root.Selected" class="group ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr" >
        <div class="accordion-header  ui-widget-header">
        <label> This is my acccordionheader </label>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-content">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="normalCheckBox filter-chkbox" value="myChkbox" data-bind="checked: myChkbox"/><label for="myChkbox" class="filter-chkbox" >Check box working?</label>   

        </div>                      
    </div>
</script>
```

Any hints and tips appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove two (2) extra closing `</div>` on the `item-template` as show below:

```
<script type="text/html" id="item-template" >
<div data-bind="attr: {'id': 'item' + itemId}, click: $root.Selected" class="group ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr" >
    <div class="accordion-header  ui-widget-header">
    <label> This is my acccordionheader </label>
    </div>
        <div class="accordion-content">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="normalCheckBox filter-chkbox" value="myChkbox" data-bind="checked: myChkbox"/><label for="myChkbox" class="filter-chkbox" >Check box working?</label>    
                </div> <!-- Remove this (1) -->
            </div> <!-- Remove this (2) -->

        </div>                      
</div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but it was merely due to hasty editing and did not reside in the original code, so problem is caused by something else.